# Software to generate a sequence of instructions

Tags: macos, software-rec, documentation

I'm looking for a desktop software that could help me record a sequence of actions on my website to then semi-automatically generate documentation for my end users. The generated documentation could be a sequence of images for example. Might be something like http://www.iorad.com/ but not as a service, rather as a software.

Does it exist? Any recommendations?

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: ---- MacOS ----

Answer (score 0):

[Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/) should do what you want.

> Wink is a Tutorial and Presentation creation software, primarily aimed at creating tutorials on how to use software (like a tutor for MS-Word/Excel etc). Using Wink you can capture screenshots, add explanations boxes, buttons, titles etc and generate a highly effective tutorial for your users.

Comment: He's on Mac OS X. Wink seems to be Windows and Linux only.

Comment: You're right. But he hadn't specified his OS in the original question.

Comment: I know, that's why I added the tags yesterday ;)

Comment: Thanks Ben, indeed I was looking a software for Mac. Thanks to your response I've checked http://alternativeto.net/software/wink/?platform=mac but looks like all generate videos, no sequences of screenshots.